# Show the expectation of the spin component $\langle \hat S_x \rangle=\hbar\,a_1a_2\cos\left(\frac{2\mu_BB\, t}{\hbar}\right)$ for real $a_1$ & $a_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, quantum-mechanics, expected-value

Using $$\langle \hat S_x \rangle ={\chi_{s}}^{\dagger}(t) \hat S_x \chi_s(t)=\frac{\hbar}{2}{\chi_{s}}^{\dagger}(t)\sigma_x\chi_s(t)\tag{1}$$
where the time dependent $2$ - component spin vector is
$$\chi_s(t)=\begin{bmatrix}\chi_1(t)  \\  \chi_2(t)\end{bmatrix}$$
and 
$$\chi_1(t)=a_1\exp\left(\frac{-i\mu_BB\,t}{\hbar}\right)$$
$$\chi_2(t)=a_2\exp\left(\frac{i\mu_BB\,t}{\hbar}\right)$$ 
and the Pauli spin matrix 
$$\sigma_x=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

$\mu_B$ is the Bohr magneton.

So from $(1)$

$$\begin{align}\langle \hat S_x \rangle &=\frac{\hbar}{2}{\chi_{s}}^{\dagger}(t)\sigma_x\chi_s(t)\\&=
\frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}{\chi_1}^*(t) & {\chi_2}^*(t)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}{\chi_1}(t) \\ {\chi_2}(t)\end{pmatrix}\\&=\frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}{\chi_1}^*(t) & {\chi_2}^*(t)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}{\chi_2}(t) \\ {\chi_1}(t)\end{pmatrix}\\&=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left({\chi_1}^*(t){\chi_2}(t)+{\chi_2}^*(t){\chi_1}(t)\right)\\&=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left({a_1}^*\exp\left(\frac{i \mu_BB\, t}{\hbar}\right)a_2\exp\left(\frac{i \mu_BB\, t}{\hbar}\right)+{a_2}^*\exp\left(\frac{-i \mu_BB\, t}{\hbar}\right)a_1\exp\left(\frac{-i \mu_BB\, t}{\hbar}\right)\right)\\&=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left({a_1}^*a_2\exp\left(\frac{2i \mu_BB\, t}{\hbar}\right)+a_1{a_2}^*\exp\left(\frac{-2i \mu_BB\, t}{\hbar}\right)\right)\end{align}$$

This is as far as I can seem to get. I am trying to make use of the result that $$2\cos\left(\frac{2\mu_BB\, t}{\hbar}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{2i \mu_BB\, t}{\hbar}\right)+\exp\left(\frac{-2i \mu_BB\, t}{\hbar}\right)$$ I note that the second term in the bracket of the last equation of $\langle \hat S_x \rangle$ is the complex conjugate of the first term in that bracket. Even with this knowledge, I am still confused about how to complete this proof.

Could someone please provide me with any hints or advice to prove that 
$$\langle \hat S_x \rangle=\hbar\,a_1a_2\cos\left(\frac{2\mu_BB\, t}{\hbar}\right)?$$

Comment: If I trust your calculations, then the result should be
$$\left\langle\hat{S}_x\right\rangle=\hbar \,\text{Re}\left(a_1a_2^*\right)\,\cos\left(\frac{2\pi \mu_B Bt}{\hbar}\right)+\hbar\,\text{Im}\left(a_1a_2^*\right)\,\sin\left(\frac{2\pi \mu_B Bt}{\hbar}\right)\,.$$
Is there any assumption that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are real numbers?

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks for your reply, sorry I forgot to mention that $a_1$ & $a_2$ are real. I will edit the question now. Many thanks.